# Why is this not adding weeks?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I have this NSDate category to easily add or subtract from a date. Days, Months, and Years all work fine, however weeks doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
- (NSDate *)addDays:(int)days
              weeks:(int)weeks
             months:(int)months
              years:(int)years {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit  fromDate:self];

    if (days) {
        [comps setDay:[comps day] + days];
    }

    if (weeks) {
        [comps setWeek:[comps week] + weeks];
    }

    if (months) {
        [comps setMonth:[comps month] + months];
    }

    if (years) {
        [comps setYear:[comps year] + years];
    }

    NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];

    return nextDate;
}
```

Calling it:

```
NSDate *showDate = [NSDate date];        
showDate = [showDate addDays:0 weeks:1 months:0 years:0];
```

For given date: 2014-06-19 14:00:11 +0000, I expect an output of 2014-06-26 04:00:00 +0000. It remains unchanged.

Comment: Can you show us some output and expected output?

Comment: Any specific reason why you are not using `dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:` and you add the components manually?

Comment: I do see that using the dateByAddingComponents is working properly. I still wonder why the prior way is failing though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `-[NSCalendar dateFromComponents:]` documentation:

> When there is inconsistent information, a calendar may ignore some of the components parameters or the method may return nil. Unnecessary components are ignored (for example, Day takes precedence over Weekday and Weekday ordinals).

Even when you are adding only weeks, `day` is still set for the `NSDateComponents` instance . You will get a collision between `day` and `week` and the `week` will be ignored.

For example, today is:

```
19 Jun 2014, Week 25
```

if I add `10` to week

```
19 Jun 2014, Week 35
```

Then `19 Jun` obviously collides with `Week 35`.

To fix it, create a new `NSDateComponents` instance:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

[comps setDay:days];
[comps setWeek:weeks];
[comps setMonth:months];
[comps setYear:years];
```

and use

```
NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:comps
                                             toDate:self
                                            options:0];
```